# jQuery .css('right') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a simple game in jQuery. I am having trouble turning the spider image to north east. I have it working fine with north west but for some reason north east does not seem to be working. Here is my init code:

```
// JavaScript Document
function init(){

    angel = $('<img class="spider">').attr({
        'src': 'img/spider.png'
    }).css({
        width: "125px",
        height: "125px;",
        'position': 'absolute',
        top: -10,
        left: -10
    });

    //append it to body
    $(document.body).append(angel);

    //start dreaming
    do_dream();
}
```

Here is my part of the code that is responsible for turning it north east or north west. Like I said earlier, north west seems to work perfectly fine but when the same code is used for turning it north east, it does not work.

```
// turn north west
     if (parseInt(dream.css('top')) < parseInt(angel.css('top')) && parseInt(dream.css('left')) < parseInt(angel.css('left'))) { 
         $('.spider').attr('src', 'img/spider_nw.png'); 
     }

    // turn north east
     if (parseInt(dream.css('top')) < parseInt(angel.css('top')) && parseInt(dream.css('right')) < parseInt(angel.css('right'))) { 
         $('.spider').attr('src', 'img/spider_ne.png'); 
     }
```

Comment: I'm curious why you'd only put certain `css()` parameters, like `position`, within quotes `'`, yet not all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Right" isn't working, because the CSS attribute for `right` is set to "auto". You have to calculate the right offset, using (replace your current right-compare expression by this):

```
(dream.parent().width() - dream.width() - dream.offset().left) <
(angel.parent().width() - angel.width() - angel.offset().left)
```

Comment: Would I have to do the same for bottom? If so, how would I calculate the bottom offset?

Answer (score 2):

@rob-w had explained the reason and also had given a way to solve it.

Another way is, you can always set all the four properties- left, right, top, bottom. *Don't need to set height and width then.* Like -

```
    //width: "200px",
    //height: "200px;",
    'position': 'absolute',
    top: y - 100,
    left: x - 100,
    right: x + 100, //(x - 100 + 200)
    bottom: y + 100, //(y - 100 + 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, it's because a DOM element will only have the "bottom" and "right" attributes if it's been positioned with them. That is, the browser / jQuery will not automatically compute the distance from the right edge of the window / document for you when you do `.css('right')`.

If what you want to find is the position of the right edge of the element, try adding the position of the left edge and the width.